# Best way to resize our custom image with magento code

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, image-resizing

I am trying to resize my images using magento `Varien_Image` class.But when i want to change image dimension i have to empty my resized folder every time.I tired doing this.any solution when i make change in dimension and it will automatically recreate image of that dimension.Below code or function i used for the resize.

```
public function getProductImage($image,$width = 270,$height = 270){
     if($image!="" && file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.$image)){

        $_imageUrl = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.$image;
        $imageResized = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'resized/'.$image;
        if (!file_exists($imageResized)&&file_exists($_imageUrl)) {
           $imageObj = new Varien_Image($_imageUrl);
            $imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
            $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
            $imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
            $imageObj->quality(100);
            $imageObj->resize($width, null);
            $imageObj->save($imageResized);
        $resizedURL = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . "resized/" . $image;
            return $resizedURL;
        } 
        elseif(file_exists($imageResized)) {
             $resizedURL = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . "resized/" . $image;
            return $resizedURL;    
        }
        else{
            return Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$image;    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return  Mage::getBaseUrl('media')."banner/resized/240X/placeholder.png";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the  width with folder structure like following to save different size images in different folder.

$imageResized = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'resized/'.$width.'/'.$image;

Comment: This resize function dear `$imageObj->setAllowRenameFiles(true);` so give erorr

Comment: Actually the function I have mention is define in Varien_File_Uploader class. 
Second approach would be suitable for you